# Error multiplicar columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Solicito de su ayuda con el fin de atender un error en un `dataframe` de `pandas`.

Estoy haciendo un bucle donde pueda multiplicar una columna con números dependiendo de otra columna. Por ejemplo, si en la columna `a` en la primera fila tiene 15 y en la columna `b` en la primera fila tiene `días` se multiplicará el primer número de la columna `a`  por 24 (para sacar las horas en esos días), y así sucesivamente. Se realizaron 8 bucles ya que se tiene 8 columnas con tiempo.

A continuación muestro uno de mis bucles donde  la columna `Tipo_I` es el tipo de tiempo (días, horas o minutos) y en `Tiempo_I` (la cantidad). A partir de aquí se creará una columna con el nombre de `tiempo_actividadI` donde se almacenarán los resultados. Este es uno de los 8 bucles.

```
if df1.loc[a,'Tipo_I']== 'Días':
    df1.loc[a,'tiempo_actividadI'] = df1.loc[a,'Tiempo_I'] * 24
elif df1.loc[a,'Tipo_I']== 'Horas':
    df1.loc[a,'tiempo_actividadI'] = df1.loc[a,'Tiempo_I']         
elif df1.loc[a,'Tipo_I']== 'Minutos':
    df1.loc[a,'tiempo_actividadI'] = df1.loc[a,'Tiempo_I'] / 60
elif df1.loc[a,'Tipo_I']== 0:
    df1.loc[a,'tiempo_actividadI'] = 0
else:
    df1.loc[a,'tiempo_actividadI'] = 0
```

El problema es que todos los valores de la última fila son igual a 0, tal y como se muestra en la imagen, algo que no debería de ser ya que la última columna también tiene información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo de aclarar que las 8 columnas están en formato `integer`, por lo que no creo que sea la razón de la falla.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: podrías colocar el archivo `.csv`?

Comment: Según tu texto, dices que hay que mirar la columna b para saber si son días u horas, pero tu código mira la columna a.... `df1.loc[a,'Tipo_I']== 'Días'`. ¿no debería ser algo tipo `df.loc[, df.b=="Días"]`?